# kendo datepicker does not accept its own dates in popup editing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-mvc, kendo-datetimepicker

I am using kendo ui grid with popup editing. When I edit a row a dialog is displayed. One of the fields is a date represented by kendo datetimepicker.

I get this error when I choose a date:

[image]

Why is this date invalid, I used the control to set it?!

Comment: What is the code behind that input? It looks like it is currently a DateTime but it wants a date. You might want to use the attribute [DataType(DataType.Date)] on the date property

Comment: great that solved it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the attribute

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
```

On the date property.